# Changing Gnumeric text import export default settings

Tags: csv, gnumeric

I am using the Gnumeric spreadsheet to import, update, then export csv files delimited by the pipe "|" separator.  Gnumeric by default saves it's files as xml via its .gnumeric file extension.  Therefore a user needs to import files via Data > Get External Data > Import Text file. Then the user must navigate the wizard to select import options.  These default settings are not "remembered" the next time a user imports a file.  The process is supposed to be similar for exporting (via Save As > Text (Configurable), but I did not see the export wizard.

Is there a way to change Gnumeric's DEFAULT settings so it will import/export .csv files with the pipe separator and treat all data as text (not general)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that at the moment. The easiest way to implement this feature might be a new plugin.

Comment: Ok, I will have to live with that for the time being.

Comment: FWIW, I would like Gnumeric to handle csv file import/exports similar to LibreOffice's Calc which saves your most recent import/export settings and does not "mess" with your data by assuming a default "General" data type for all columns.  That behavior will change your date fields to their standard - very bad...  Gnumeric is nice because it is a small/powerfull standalone spreadsheet that I can install on a liveCD.  Whereas, Calc must be installed with the entire (and huge) LibreOffice suite.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Ok, I submitted an enhancement request to: "Persist Gnumeric csv import/export settings".  See: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=695588

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem writing a wrapper-script gnumeric.sh that converted - in my case - semicolons to commas (and before that commas to `::`), wrote that to a temporary file and opened that file with gnumeric (the csv came from server-genearted data saved/opened from a browser)

Turns out I still ran into the same or a similar trap, because gnumeric autodetects date formats wrong… something that would be configurable, but not from the command line.